# Spring security, LDAP and SSO

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I am trying to build an application where login is done by siteminder SSO. Once login is done I need to get the user info(like roles,permissions) for logged in user from LDAP and put in session.

Aslo I am using spring MVC to expose REST services. I want my rest services to be accessible only for certain roles(Like Manager/Admin etc). Also UI will display/hide pages based roles.

I want to know what is the best approach to achieve the above.

Please note I am using spring MVC on WAS7.

Comment: I too have a similar requirement, any help is appreciated.